# is that important to clean data when use self.kwargs.get()?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

is that important to clean data when use `self.kwargs.get()`?
for example when we get pk from url in view classes by `self.kwargs.get(pk)`.I use pk when I write sql queries.
if answer is yes, how can I clean data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the value in the ORM, then Django will take care of escaping for you.

```
slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
obj = MyModel.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

If you are writing raw SQL then you should use parameters if possible to prevent SQL injection.

```
slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
cursor.execute("SELECT title FROM my_model WHERE slug = %s", [slug])
```

If you are doing string concatenation with `self.kwargs.get()` then you're potentially at risk of SQL injection. The risk depends on the URL patterns, for example if your named group is `(<?P<pk>[0-9]+>)`, then `self.kwargs['pk']` couldn't be used for SQL injection because it can only consist of the digits `0-9`.

Comment: thanks, I write raw SQL like this: `Content.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM ertaapp_content where course_id=%s',[self.kwargs.get('pk')])` , and just get pks from `self.kwargs.get()`